# String Compare issues in C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, strcmp

So the assignment is this: Problem C: Practice Strings  (lastnames.c)(8 points)

Read in n, then n lastnames, and check to see if the first in the list is ever repeated again.

Sample Run #1

Enter n, followed by n Last names (each last name must be a single word):

5 Reagan Bush Clinton Bush Obama

First name in list is not repeated.

Sample Run #2

Enter n, followed by n Last names (each last name must be a single word):

4 Bush Clinton Bush Obama

First name in list is repeated.

I can get the first two names to compare, but I can't figure out how to compare the first to whatever is in the second string array. I don't want to post my code in the event that someone searches this and copies mine. I'll send it to you though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{   
// initializing character strings
char last[25], first[25];

// initializing number of names, and the index for the number of names
int index, n;

// read in the number
printf("Enter n, followed by n Last names (each last name must be a single word) :\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
scanf("%s", first);

for (index = 0; index < n; index++) 
    scanf("%s", last);

if (strcmp(last, first)== 0)
{
    printf("First name in list is repeated.\n"); 
}
else 
{
    printf("First name in list is not repeated.\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is expected, that a question is accompanied by a presentation what the person has tried so far. This includes source code. Considering, that you have not even solved the problem, it is very unlikely that anyone will copy it.

Comment: Show us what you have done, then ask for help. In StackOverflow everyone like to help eachother and share their knowledge. Asking to do your assignment is not the right thing to do :(

Comment: there are far more entertaining and important pieces of code to rip from the breaches of the world wide web than an incomplete solution to problem-c of a a fundamental C language course. If you want to know what you're doing wrong, post your code.

Comment: The reason I haven't wanted to post it is so no one else in my class will copy it. But I guess I will take that risk

Comment: @ThanushanBalakrishnan any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char last[25], first[25];
    int index, n, repeated = 0;

    printf("Enter n, followed by n Last names (each last name must be a single word) :\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    scanf("%s", first);

    for(index = 1; index < n; index++){ //index = 1 : aleady input first
        scanf("%s", last);
        if(strcmp(last, first)== 0)
            repeated = 1;
    }
    if(repeated)
        printf("First name in list is repeated.\n");
    else 
        printf("First name in list is not repeated.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `for`loop the `last`variable is overwritten every time which means that you are only comparing the first input to the last name in the next sequence of `n` lastnames.

If you want to count the number of repetitions, use a counter within the for-loop.

```
int nRepetitions = 0;

/* ... read the numbers and the first string 
      (therefore index should start with 1)... */

for (index = 1; index < n; index++) {
    scanf("%s", last);
    if (strcmp(last, first) == 0) {
        nRepetitions++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, so using a 2D array I could fix this issue. I still don't get how to implement the 2D array in.

Comment: No need for a 2D array in this case. Just add a counter for repetitions within the first loop. Also note that index should start from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incorrect..
For loop `last` has just 1D character array and which is overwritten everytime.
So Use a 2D array instead..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{   
// initializing character strings
char first[25];

// initializing number of names, and the index for the number of names
int index=0, n;

// read in the number
printf("Enter the number of last names :\n");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("Enter the first name \n");
scanf("%s", first);

char last[n][25];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    scanf("%s", last[i]);

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if (strcmp(last[i], first)== 0)
        index++;
}
if(index==0)
    printf("First name not repeated\n");
else
    printf("First name repeated %d times", index);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I see what you mean about using a 2D array, but I'm still not getting it.

Comment: index == 0 would never render true because of its increment, which is why I'm stuck.

Comment: It would be zero if none matches..Check this http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php